# Micronaut CompileStatic JSON object -Static type checking- No such property: bookid for class: java.lang.Object

Tags: groovy, micronaut

In my Micronaut Controller I have below code to parse the JSON object. when I use `@CompileStatic` annotation it throwing this below error.

```
  @Post("/save")   
   def save(@Body Object JSON) {
    String bookid=JSON?.bookid
      String name=JSON?.name
    def b =bookService.save(bookid,name)
    return HttpResponse.created(b)
   }
```

**Error**

```
BookController.groovy: 58: [Static type checking] - No such property: bookid for class: java.lang.Object
```

Is there way to fix this error message with compilestatic annotation?

Thanks
SR

Comment: I'm not a micronaut guy, but in Groovy if you use CompileStatic then you should mostly try to avoid Object, since it won't have compile-time access to anything you want in the Body there.  You'll probably want to create a type that has `bookid` and `name` fields, and bind to it using `@Body`.  Here's some docs on binding: https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#binding

Comment: @billjamesdev, Thanks for the Point Jeff Brown example helped me. here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000199/micronaut-json-post-strip-the-qutoes/54000735#54000735

Comment: Curses, that @jeff-scott-brown guy sure is smart :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Help of Jeff Brown I have changed. my save method like this.

```
  @Post('/')
    Book save(Book b) {
        bookService.save b
    }
```

[Micronaut JSON post strip the Qutoes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000199/micronaut-json-post-strip-the-qutoes/54000735#54000735)

Answer (score 1):

You can also work with your method instead of changing it for parsing.I encountered the same problem and the method that worked for me is using String instead of object. Just use JSON String along with @BODY and then parse it using ObjectMapper().

here is the answer i posted at some other question, hope it will help you out.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54905403/7803105